# Remove carriage return from output in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimerepl

I'm learning ipython for data analysis and I'd like to use Sublime text, my favorite text editor. However, I'm having a problem with "CR", carriage return, being output instead of the original "stuff" I want to display. This makes copying/pasting to another location a hassle because I'll have to manually delete those characters. It's also frustrating to look at.

*Here's an example from the textbook I'm using:*
[image: sublime output]

*Running the same command in terminal and it works fine*
[image: Terminal output of same command]

Although it displays properly in terminal, I really would like to use a REPL in sublime because of the helpful plugins such as autocomplete and code intelligence. I've tried changing the user settings default_line_ending but nothing helped. If someone knows how to get rid of those carriage returns or at least hide them from the output, I'd be very happy.

Thank you

Comment: What does `file names/yob1880.txt` say? Maybe try `dos2unix` or `sed -e 's/\r//'`...

Comment: @Kenney Thanks for the comment. It's just a plaintext file with name, gender, amount of births on each line. I tried converting to unix but I'm still getting the CR's in the output.

Comment: Okay. The `file` command on a plain text file with unix line endings would say 'ASCII Text'; for a DOS file 'ASCII Text, with CRLF line terminators', and in your case I wouldn't know what it says. It looks to me the line endings are CRCRLF (`\r\r\n`, you could verify with `hexdump -C`: there would be `0d 0d 0a` patterns), and need to be fixed; there's no setting in any editor that I know that fixes that. Do you know how to [search and replace](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace.html) a `\r` with an empty string in regexp mode?

Comment: @Kenney didnt realize that was a command, the output is "names/yob1880.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators". Also there are no "0d 0d 0a" patterns in the hexdump, just "0d 0a"

Answer (score 3):

If your terminal supports it, you can try the following command to remove the existing CRs:

sed -i 's/\r//g' FileWithCarriageReturns.foo

sed is a stream editing command which when executed as above, will search through the specified 'FileWithCarriageReturns.sh' and remove all carriage returns (seen as \r ) from the file

Once you've done that, go into your Sublime Text settings and override the default line ending property to be 'unix' :

{
    "default_line_ending" : "unix"
}